# .htaccess RewriteRule not working with querystrings as directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/|#(.*))$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)/$ $1.php?id=$2
```

I had problems with with the absolute URI, it solved. Now I want to use the last row for the following:

`domain.com/query/ping/2/`

to

`domain.com/query/ping.php?id=2`

I think the code is good, but I still get back error 404. Should I give some rewrite conditions? I searched for this code but haven't found anything useful.

Comment: Is `/query` supposed to be in the URI? Is the htaccess file in your `query` directory? EDIT: Oh, you're the guy who asked about the previous relative URL problem, you should consider clicking on the green check mark next to correct answers so your question gets marked as "Resolved")

Comment: /query has to be there since it is a directory, the .htaccess is in root Done, thanks for the advice. Do you have any idea regarding this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on where you've placed your htaccess file in your previous question, you probably want something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/query/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/query/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^ /query/%1.php?id=%2 [L]
```

The important issue is that you need to check for `/query` in the beginning of the URI. What you have, `^([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)/$` won't match the `/query` part along with the 2 pathnames after it. Your regex only matches 2 pathnames.

The line `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/query/%1.php -f` is similar to the condition you have above where it checks to see if the requested PHP file actually exists, otherwise it won't blindly rewrite. This condition ensures if someone tries to go to:

`http://domain.com/query/blahblahblahblah/blah`

Your server won't return a 404 error saying `/query/blahblahblahblah.php` doesn't exist.